# tkinter, how to display dataframe.describe() in a Treeview?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I'm stuck on a little problem and I need your help.

I'm trying to display dataframe.describe() in a treeview on Tkinter.

But the problem is that I can't display the first column of operations [count, mean, std, min...]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98UqT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQMBE.png)

this is my code :

```
    listBox = ttk.Treeview(frame_describe, height=10)
    listBox.pack(fill=X)

    desc = df.describe()

    listBox["column"] = list(desc.columns)
    listBox["show"] = "headings"

    for column in listBox["column"]:
        listBox.heading(column, text=column)
        listBox.column(column,anchor=CENTER)

    desc = df.describe().to_numpy().tolist()

    for row in desc:
        listBox.insert("", "end", values=row)
```

Comment: Use `desc = df.describe().reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()`.

Comment: thank you very much.
the indexs appeared in the first column instead of generating a new one, but I'll find out. you have already helped me a lot ;)

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the question. Instead, write an answer. See [answer] for more information.